# How do I hook up multiple buttons to change a single variable in an algorithm?

Tags: java, button, random, numbers, generator

I am working on a "dice rolling" experiment as I am a complete newcomer and I seem to be learning a lot from it. But I am stuck at this one place and can't seem to find any help.

I have a random number generator hooked up where I can edit the number of "sides" a die would have with a user manually imputing the numbers. I would like the user to be able to press one of the buttons that I added, and have the calculated random result show up at the bottom. I am not sure how to do this, so I would appreciate some insight, even if it's just a single line.

Also, please tell me if there is anything I am doing wrong in any way at all, I am really REALLY new at this, and could use some help!

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.applet.Applet;





public class randtest6t extends Applet
{ 


public static void main(String[] args)
{
int dieSides;
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("How many sides does the die need to be?");
dieSides = keyboard.nextInt();
int random = (int )(Math.random() * dieSides + 1);
System.out.println("You rolled a " + random + ".");



 //NAMING BUTTONS
 JButton button2 = new JButton("2");
 JButton button4 = new JButton("4");
 JButton button6 = new JButton("6");
 JButton button8 = new JButton("8");
 JButton button10 = new JButton("10");
 JButton button12 = new JButton("12");
 JButton button20 = new JButton("20");
 JButton button50 = new JButton("50");
 JButton button100 = new JButton("100");


 //LABELS
 JLabel sides = new JLabel("How many sides does the die need to be?");
 JLabel text = new JLabel("Your roll =");
 JLabel output = new JLabel("             " + random );

 output.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 56));
 text.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 20));
 sides.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 20));




 //NAMING PANELS
 JPanel buttonpanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,3));
 JPanel outputpanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,2));

 //CONNECTING BUTTONS/TEXT/PANELS
 outputpanel.add( text );
 outputpanel.add( output );

 buttonpanel.add( button2 );
 buttonpanel.add( button4 );
 buttonpanel.add( button6 );
 buttonpanel.add( button8 );
 buttonpanel.add( button10 );
 buttonpanel.add( button12 );
 buttonpanel.add( button20 );
 buttonpanel.add( button50 );
 buttonpanel.add( button100 );

 JFrame diceFrame = new JFrame("Dice Roll");

 diceFrame.add( sides, BorderLayout.NORTH );
 diceFrame.add( outputpanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
 diceFrame.add( buttonpanel, BorderLayout.CENTER );
 diceFrame.setSize(500,500);

 diceFrame.setVisible(true);
 diceFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
   public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
     System.exit(0);
   }
 });
}
}
```

Sorry if I formatted wrong or anything, I would really appreciate your help!

Also to be clear, what I want to happen is this:

1. button2 pressed
2. dieSides = 2
3. int random = (int )(Math.random() * dieSides + 1);
4. Display result on the JFrame

The problem I am having is that I can not have dieSides be dependent on the button that is pressed.

Comment: You could have each button call a method that takes the number of sides as a parameter. That way, each button could call the same method but specify the number of sides.

Comment: You have to have an event handler for each button and reassign the value for output and refresh the window to get it to show up

Answer (score 0):

All of your action happens in the `main()` method.  What you need to do is separate some of that functionality out into other methods you can call.  For example, in `main()` you could setup all the buttons/panels, listeners, etc and then wait for a click.  It doesn't look like you have any listeners on your buttons, you will need to add an `ActionListener` (a separate class or subclass that you instantiate and pass to each button's `addActionListener(Listener)` method).  Then each button should call a method like `rollDie(int dieSides)`, where x is unique to each button, i.e. button2 should call `rollDie(2);`

That will get your buttons working.

Finally, the `rollDie(int dieSides)` method should contain your call to Math.Random().

Now you have to figure out how to update the panel that displays the numerical output with the number `rollDie(int)` generated.  For example `rollDie(int)` could store than number inside a class-level variable, and another method like `updateOutputPanel()` could be called by each button to update the `JLabel` with the new number.